# How to send Integer to the Server in ios?

Tags: ios

I am sending my `ZipCode` to the server as a String, it works as follows.

```
NSString *zip = self.product.zipCode;
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"zip\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:zip] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

However, I wonder how I could able to send the `ZipCode` as an integer?

Comment: could you please illustrate with an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you're asking here.  Since you're baking the zip code into a string to send it anyway, it doesn't matter whether you have it as a string or as an integer.  I *suspect* what you mean is that you want it as an integer on the server side once you receive it, perhaps?  If so, that depends on what language you're scripting the server with.

However, either way, you should be aware that **zip codes are not integers**.  Zip codes can have more than just the five digits.  For instance, many zip codes have the form: "XXXXX-XXXX" (where "X" is a digit from 0 to 9).  If you try to cast that as an integer, you'll actually lose part of the zip code.  Keep zip codes as strings if you want to retain them as they are entered.

[More info here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_code#ZIP.2B4)